# Cannot convert type of Int to expected value [MyCustomType]

Tags: swift, swift3

Xcode 8.3.3 is giving me this Swift 3 error on this line

```
values2[index] = nextValue(currentValue)
```

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Card'

Here's my code:

```
//
//  Card.swift
//  match
//
//  Created by quantum on 05/09/2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 Quantum Productions. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class Card: NSObject {
    var quantity = 0
    var fill = 0
    var shape = 0
    var color = 0

    override var description : String {
        return "Q" + String(quantity) + "/F" + String(fill) + "/S" + String(shape) + "/C" + String(color)
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    static func properties() -> [String] {
        return ["quantity", "fill", "shape", "color"]
    }

    static func isMatch(cards: [Card]) -> Bool {
        for property in self.properties() {
            var sum = 0
            for card in cards {
                sum = sum + (card.value(forKey: property) as! Int)
            }
            if !([3, 6, 9, 7].contains(sum)) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    static func deck(_ values: [Int], _ index: Int, _ max: Int, _ acc: [Card]) -> [Card]{
        let currentValue = values[index]
        var values2 = values
        if currentValue >= max {
            if index == 0 {
                return acc
            }

            values2[index] = 0
            values2[index-1] = values2[index-1] + 1
            return deck(values, index - 1, max, acc)
        } else {
            var acc2 = acc
            let card = Card()
            for (index, element) in self.properties().enumerated() {
                card.setValue(values[index], forKey: element)
            }
            acc2.append(Card())
            values2[index] = nextValue(Card())
            return deck(values2, index, max, acc2)
        }
    }

    func nextValue(_ v: Int) -> Int {
        if (v == 0) {
            return 1
        } else if (v == 1) {
            return 2
        }

        return 4
    }

    static func deck() -> [Card] {
        return deck([1,1,1,1], 4, 3, [Card]())
    }
}
```

this is inside of my `Card` class.

Strangely, if I try (this is wrong, I'm testing the compiler error)

```
   values2[index] = nextValue(Card())
```

I get the error `Cannot assign the value  of type (Int) -> Int to type 'Int'`.

Swift thinks my `Card` is an `Int`? I'm confused as to what's happening.

I expected to get the call nextvalue with the variable currentvalue, which should be an Int.

Comment: What is the point of your question?  Your code indicates that Card is a custom class or struct.  Yet, you don't even show its definition.  Far from that, you don't even say at what line you get an error.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can show complete card class

Comment: Complete code shown.
I included the line with the error in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad error message from the compiler.

Your problem is that `deck` is declared `static`, but you're trying to call `nextValue` which is not declared `static`.   This means that `nextValue` implicitly takes a hidden argument, `self`, but `deck` isn't providing it.

If you add `static` to the `func nextValue` declaration, it will work like you expect.  (You'll get an error on the line referring to `self.properties` instead, but you'll be closer.)

To make this work properly, you probably want all these functions to be non-static instead.  Just think about how this code gets called initially (i.e. how you get your first instance of `Card`).

Answer (score 1):

A static method cannot call an instance method: the idea makes no sense, as there is no instance. Thus your reference to `nextValue` is impossible. That is why the line is problematic. How can a static method `deck` call an instance method `nextValue`?